# Locking a specific command in cmd.exe

Tags: security, windows-xp, system-administration

Can anyone recommend a way in Windows XP or later to make it possible for users to access cmd.exe while locking out the ability to use `type`?

Comment: What purpose would that serve ?

Comment: The purpose is to allow access to cmd for diagnostic purposes, while locking out the ability to read proprietary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you could prevent the use of `type`, the following command would do the same thing:

```
copy file.txt con
```

There are probably other ways to display the contents of a file without using the `type` built-in command. Notepad (or any other text editor) jumps to mind.

Comment: yeah, you could use a web browser even... in fact it's impossible to stop the reading of all files as it's a core operating system function. One however can use ntfs ACLs to restrict just which files can be read(yes it's possible on win XP).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that type is built into the shell's command parser itself, so I'm thinking no.

Answer (score 0):

You could always make type.bat (which does nothing), or even compile type.exe and put it in path.

Comment: Making a .bat or .exe does not override the built-in command.

Comment: Hmm, yes. It would seem so. I'm mixing up things, this used to work fine in the dos days.